# pushViewController not working with IOS11 SDK

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

The code below is not changing to the view controller as it does in the app store currently. only change is the new Xcode/IOS11 SDK. I did some google searches and found some others who had the same issue but were able to resolved by deleting derived data and restarted or turning `animated:NO` but neither has worked for me...

the code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];  

     // Set up observers etc code omitted....  

     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];    

     Home *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];  
     NSLog(@"Nav Controller: %@",self.navigationController); // Output: Nav Controller: <UINavigationController: 0x7fc2d182d800>  
     NSLog(@"View Controller: %@",viewController); // Output: View Controller: <Home: 0x7fc2d0717cc0>  
     [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; // No change to different view controller.  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are facing the same issue, push view controller is not working from `viewDidAppear`. When we investigate issue we found navigation viewController have that view on top but not appearing on screen. Try to push controller in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` block it will work.

PS. That issue resolved in iOS 11.1.

Comment: I have pushViewController wrapped as you recommended in ObjectiveC and while it works for a bit, it no longer animates after a few pushes.

Comment: It's probably important to note that I'm pushing and then popping back to the screen I made the push on.

Answer (score -1):

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

try this

Comment: Didn’t work, that’s actually how it was initially but I was trying different ways per something I found online...

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you find anything? have same issue, things that were working before are no more working on xcode 8, ios 11

Comment: The answer above fixed it.